# How to refresh randint in python 3

Tags: python

Hi I was wondering how to make a randint refresh itself. I'll make an example:

```
import random
from random import randint
import time
number = random.randint(1,3)
test = 0
while test <=10:
    print (number)
    test +=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

so if I ran that and got 2, the random number be 2 every time. Is there any way to make it refresh itself?

Comment: It is not related to the question and only a suggestion. You used `import random` and `from random import randint`. It is not needed to import twice as you are using `random.randint(1,3)`, so in this case `import randon` is sufficient or else use the other way.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the call to `random.randint` inside the loop:

```
test = 0
while test <=10:
    print (random.randint(1,3))
    test +=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now it will be called once per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

`randint` is a function that *returns a single random number*, it's not a magic thing that "infects" the variable making it change value each time you read it.

If you want another random number, you have to call `randint` again; in your case moving the call inside the loop will do.